# Apache2 OpenLDAP authorization fails using ldap-user

Tags: apache-2.4, openldap, http-basic-authentication

I have an Apache2 server running in a Docker container (httpd:2.4.54-bullseye), and an LDAP server (OpenLDAP slapd 2.4.57+dfsg-3 on Debian 11.1)

I'm trying to use `mod_authnz_ldap` Apache module to authenticate certain users from the LDAP.

Here is the config of Apache :

```
<AuthnProviderAlias ldap org>
  AuthLDAPURL ldap://org.com/dc=org,dc=com?uid
</AuthnProviderAlias>

<VirtualHost _default_:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs

    <Location "/">
        AuthName "Apache2 LDAP Check"
        AuthType Basic
        AuthBasicProvider org
        Require ldap-user me collegue1 collegue2
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

According to the [docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authnz_ldap.html#requser) I should only put uids in `Require ldap-user` .
The logs show that the authentication is done successfully, but it can't authorize any of the users in `Require ldap-user` !!

```
web_auth   | [Tue Aug 30 09:09:13.594015 2022] [authz_core:debug] [pid 10:tid 139920102389504] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client 192.168.103.66:2189] AH01626: authorization result of Require ldap-user me collegue1 collegue2: denied (no authenticated user yet)
web_auth   | [Tue Aug 30 09:09:13.594064 2022] [authz_core:debug] [pid 10:tid 139920102389504] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client 192.168.103.66:2189] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: denied (no authenticated user yet)
web_auth   | [Tue Aug 30 09:09:13.594137 2022] [authnz_ldap:debug] [pid 10:tid 139920102389504] mod_authnz_ldap.c(548): [client 192.168.103.66:2189] AH01691: auth_ldap authenticate: using URL ldap://org.com/dc=org,dc=com?uid
web_auth   | [Tue Aug 30 09:09:13.599377 2022] [authnz_ldap:debug] [pid 10:tid 139920102389504] mod_authnz_ldap.c(630): [client 192.168.103.66:2189] AH01697: auth_ldap authenticate: accepting me
web_auth   | [Tue Aug 30 09:09:13.599404 2022] [authz_core:debug] [pid 10:tid 139920102389504] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client 192.168.103.66:2189] AH01626: authorization result of Require ldap-user me collegue1 collegue2: denied
web_auth   | [Tue Aug 30 09:09:13.599411 2022] [authz_core:debug] [pid 10:tid 139920102389504] mod_authz_core.c(815): [client 192.168.103.66:2189] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: denied
web_auth   | [Tue Aug 30 09:09:13.599417 2022] [authz_core:error] [pid 10:tid 139920102389504] [client 192.168.103.66:2189] AH01631: user me: authorization failure for "/":
```

Am I missing something ?

PS: When I use `Require valid-user` everything work just fine!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am I missing something ?

Possibly! I was playing with this configuration a bit this morning, and I see exactly the same behavior you've described. First, my test configuration looks like this:

```
<AuthnProviderAlias ldap example>
  AuthLDAPURL ldap://ldap/ou=users,dc=example,dc=com?cn
  AuthLDAPBindDN uid=authreader,ou=system,dc=example,dc=com
  AuthLDAPBindPassword secret
</AuthnProviderAlias>

<Location "/">
  AuthName "LDAP"
  AuthType Basic
  AuthBasicProvider example
  Require ldap-user user1
</Location>
```

And I have an LDAP directory for `dc=example,dc=com` that includes `cn=user1,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com` and `cn=user2,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com`.

I enabled debug logging (`LogLevel debug`) in my server, and watching the logs during an authentication attempt I see:

```
... AH01697: auth_ldap authenticate: accepting user1
... AH01626: authorization result of Require ldap-user user1: denied
```

That's interesting, because it shows that `mod_authnz_ldap` is correctly authenticating the user. On a hunch, I replaced:

```
Require ldap-user user1
```

With:

```
Require user user1
```

And to my surprise, everything Just Worked. So, that's great, but does that mean all the documentation is wrong? That seems unlikely. As far as I can tell, this has something to do with the use of the `AuthnProviderAlias` directive.

I tried replacing `Require ldap-user user1` with `Require example-user user1`, thinking that maybe the `ldap-` part was supposed to be a provider name, but that fails with:

```
Unknown Authz provider: example-user
```

So then I tried a configuration that doesn't use a provider alias:

```
<Location "/">
  AuthLDAPURL ldap://ldap/ou=users,dc=example,dc=com?cn
  AuthLDAPBindDN uid=authreader,ou=system,dc=example,dc=com
  AuthLDAPBindPassword secret

  AuthName "LDAP"
  AuthType Basic
  AuthBasicProvider ldap
  Require ldap-user user1
</Location>
```

This *also* works correctly, which I think confirms my theory that the
culprit is the provider alias.

Based on the above results, my theory is that there's a bug. It looks
like there has been some previous trouble in this area, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18874062/can-authnprovideralias-ldap-work-with-apache2-4-x.

If you need things like `Require ldap-group`, `Require ldap-group` to
work (in addition to `Require ldap-user`), it looks like the only
solution is to embed the AuthLDAP directives in the same
location/directory/etc block as the `Require` statement. If all you
need is `Require user ...` or `Require valid-user`, then using an
alias should work fine.

I'm going to try to ping some other folks to confirm that we're not
*both* missing something in the documentation.

You can find test environment for all of this [here](https://github.com/larsks/so-example-1109463).

Comment: Indeed, after moving the AuthLDAP directive inside the Location block, everything worked.
Thanks a lot for the explanation!